# Finding the union of multiple LIKE searches with searchlogic or named_scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope, searchlogic

Given a delimited string of unknown length e.g. `'peanut,banana'` or `'bacon,eggs,toast,arugula'`, I want to use named_scope or searchlogic in my rails 2.3.9 app to end up with a SQL statement like `SELECT * FROM foods WHERE (name LIKE 'peanut') OR (name LIKE 'banana')`. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Food.name_like_any("peanut", "banana")
# it also accepts an array
Food.name_like_any(["bacon", "eggs", "toast", "arugula"])
```

from the [searchlogic readme](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic)

Comment: To turn a CSV string into an array you'd do `"foo,bar,zomg".split(',')`  This plus the above is what you neeed.